# Dynamically resize a text box/table row based on table size

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have an SSRS report that contains a tablix that can be seen in the the image below.[image] The last 3 columns only appear if certain conditions are met within the HT Cycle column.  My problem is that the Heat Treatment row stays a consistent size if the last 3 columns are visible or not. Is there a way to get the title text box to resize based on the visibility of those last 3 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a text box for Heat Treatment, you should be able to add a row to the tablix above the header row. You can then merge the cells in that new top row (highlight the cells in that row -> right click -> merge cells) to give the same look that you have in your screenshot, but without having it extend past the tablix when those last 3 columns are hidden.

As far as I know, this will work as long as you do not have any column groups, which it does not appear that you do.

Comment: Sorry, it is a row within the tablix but the properties window defines it as a textbox so that is what I put. Will edit the original question to clarify this

Comment: Just to verify: you are hiding the entire 3 last columns, not just the individual cells for those columns, correct? This works for me on a test report, so I'm not sure what could be causing the difference.